# Javascript select2 selected value is null on first select

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using select2 for my dropdown menu with bootstrap and bootbox. The problem is that when I show my dropdown and try to select a value **for the first time**, it returns an empty object. If I reselect some another value, it works ok. Any ideas how this may be fixed?

My code is ass follows

```
<select name="classSelect" class="form-control classSelect select2-hidden-accessible" id="subject_change_select" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="5">sdfsdfsfsdf</option>
  <option value="6">2</option>
  <option value="7" selected="">1</option>
  <option value="8">3</option>
  <option value="9">4</option>
</select>

$(element).select2({
   language: "en",
   minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
   theme: "classic"
}).select2('open');
```

I try to get the data with the following code:

```
$('#subject_change_select').select2('data')
```

or

```
$('#subject_change_select').val()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery `.change()` to get the value of the selected input.
Then, use `.text()` to get the textvalue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        
        $( "#subject_change_select" ).change(function() {
        r = $("#subject_change_select option:selected").text();
        console.log(r);
      });

    });
      
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select name="classSelect" class="form-control classSelect select2-hidden-accessible" id="subject_change_select" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="5">sdfsdfsfsdf</option>
  <option value="6">2</option>
  <option value="7" selected="">1</option>
  <option value="8">3</option>
  <option value="9">4</option>
</select>
  </body>

</html>
```